# python matching 2 list of lists and removing match

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I want to remove from list2 any list item in the list that matches the third item in list1. I am currently trying to loop through list2 for each item in list1 and remove based on the third field.

```
list1: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

list2: [[-1,-2,3],[-4,-5,-6],[-7,-8,9],[1,2,8]]

final list2: [[-4,-5,-6],[1,2,8]]
```

My pseudocode:

```
for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        if item1[2] == item2[2]:
            remove item2[2] from list2
```

I tried some example techniques using sets and/or tuples but they are all based on removing duplicates from one list of lists; as opposed to removing items for a list of list based on one field in a separate list of lists.

Comment: rather than modifying list2, why not create a new list? `new_list = [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]` You can also make the assignment to `list2` if you wanted to.

Comment: **`remove from list2 any list item in the list that matches the third item in list1`**

Comment: @sytech did you try running that?

Comment: It was not meant to be the complete solution. Just trying to ask OP if creating a new list is acceptable. @roganjosh you can see my proposed solution below.

Comment: @sytech ah, since it's a valid list comprehension, I assumed that you thought it would give the expected output :)

Comment: The third item in `list1` is `[7,8,9]`. This equals no element of `list2`: why does `list2` change? _remove from list2 any list item where the third item matches in the corresponding_ (or _any_?!) _list item from list1_?

Comment: @greybeard the 9 is positive in both lists.

Comment: `9` is neither an element of `list1` nor of `list2`. (This might be easier to word understandably if you used a list of tuples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making a new list. You can also make an intermediary `third_items` set of all the third items in list1 that you can check against, rather than probing every element in every iteration.

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
list2 = [[-1,-2,3],[-4,-5,-6],[-7,-8,9],[1,2,8]]

third_items = set(sublist[2] for sublist in list1)
new_list = []
for sublist in list2:
    if sublist[2] not in third_items:
        new_list.append(sublist)
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[[-4, -5, -6], [1, 2, 8]]
```

or as a list comp

```
third_items = set(sublist[2] for sublist in list1)
new_list = [sublist for sublist in list2 if sublist[2] not in third_items]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  It took a little while because list1 was 170 list entries and list2 was 68,478 list entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line with list comprehensions:

```
result = [ (a) for a in list2 if a[2] not in [ (b[2]) for b in list1 ] ]
```

This is not necessarily the most efficient way of doing it but probably the most concise. If you were dealing with large lists you might want to extract the lookup first. As in:

```
lookup = [ (b[2]) for b in list1 ]
result = [ (a) for a in list2 if a[2] not in lookup ]
```

If you don't want a new list but really want to remove from list2 then:

```
lookup = [ (b[2]) for b in list1 ]
[ list2.remove(a) for a in list2 if a[2] in lookup ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if you only want to compare the corresponding elements in both lists:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list2 = [[-1, -2, 3], [-4, -5, -6], [-7, -8, 9], [1, 2, 8]]

list3 = []

for index, item in enumerate(list2):
    if index < len(list1):
        if item[2] != list1[index][2]:
            list3.append(item)
    else:
        list3.append(item)
```

If both lists have the same length, this will do:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3]]
list2 = [[-1, -2, 3], [-4, -5, -6], [-7, -8, 9], [1, 2, 8]]

if len(list1) == len(list2):
    list3 = [x for i, x in enumerate(list2) if x[2] != list1[i][2]]
```